# bxSlider and html content

Tags: html

I'm newbie and ask you to help me, although it is a beginners question:
I often work with bxSlider and everything works fine, when I embed images (jpg/png).
But now I want to show html sites inside bxSlider and I'm doing something wrong.
Inside an unordered list class, I try to do this:

```
    <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="images/pic01.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/pic02.jpg"/></li>
    <li><a href="scores/html/score01.html"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

bxSlider shows the images, but not the html site.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by sites????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

`<a href="scores/html/score01.html"></a>` is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp). If I understand your question correctly, you want to actually *show* the site inside the list.

To do this, you'll need to use an inline frame, or [`iframe`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

You implement it like this:

```
<iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>
```

Which, in your case, would obviously be

```
<iframe src="scores/html/score01.html"></iframe>
```

You'll notice that the `iframe` has a border, so you can use the `seamless` HTML5 attribute to make it look like a part of the page:

```
<iframe src="scores/html/score01.html" seamless></iframe>
```

If you want to modify the `height` and `width`, you can also use attributes:

```
<iframe src="scores/html/score01.html" height="50px" width="100px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you ver much for your help!

Comment: @digimus You're very welcome. I'm glad it worked, but it would be great if you could accept my answer by clicking the outline of a checkmark next to my question so that [we both gain reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Also feel free to upvote my answer if you found it helpful. Thanks!